# Optimizing Delta Lake Partitioning for Timestamp Range Queries

Tags: azure, pyspark, query-optimization, databricks, delta-lake

I'm working with a Delta table in Databricks that is partitioned by a `Year` column, and I have a timestamp column in the table. I want to optimize my queries to fetch data within a specific timestamp range (e.g., between 21-01-2019 and 04-12-2019).

```
df_filtered = df.filter((df.timestamp >= "2019-01-21") & (df.timestamp <= "2019-12-04"))
```

I understand that partitioning can help with performance, but I'm not sure how to leverage it effectively when querying based on a timestamp range. Even though I'm not directly querying the `Year` partition column, I'd like to take advantage of partition pruning to only read the relevant partitions.

How can I ensure that the `Year` partition column is correlated with the timestamp data effectively so that partition pruning works optimally for timestamp range queries?

Comment: Is the year field based on the year of the timestamp column?

Comment: Yes, the year column shows the year of the timestamp

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes, I'm using databricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for [Delta Table batch reads and writes](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#use-generated-columns) mentions:

> Delta Lake may be able to generate partition filters for a query whenever a partition column is defined by one of the following expressions:
>
> - YEAR(col) and the type of col is TIMESTAMP.
> - (...)

It means that if you have a table defined as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a_table (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS year(timestamp),
    [other columns]
) PARTITIONED BY (year);
```

then Databricks will be able to analyze filter conditions on `timestamp` column and derive proper partition filters for `year`. With your example:

```
df = spark.table("a_table")
df_filtered = df.filter((df.timestamp >= "2019-01-21") & (df.timestamp <= "2019-12-04"))
```

It will add a partition filter `year = 2019`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good to know this feature. I saw, that they do not recommend it anymore when liquid clustering is enabled (https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/clustering.html), but for now, that works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 2):

To optimize your queries for timestamp range queries in Databricks with a Delta table partitioned by a Year column
The below code with Year partition column is correlated with the timestamp data.

Here is how you can do it with Pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, year
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaTableExample").getOrCreate()
data = [("2020-01-15 08:00:00", "Event 1"),
        ("2020-02-20 12:30:00", "Event 2"),
        ("2021-03-10 14:45:00", "Event 3"),
        ("2019-11-05 09:15:00", "Event 4")]
columns = ["timestamp", "event_name"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
**Converting Timestamps to Date and Creating Year Partitioning Column**
df = df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("timestamp")))
df = df.withColumn("year", year(col("date")))
delta_path = "/FileStore/tables/dileep_delta_table"  
df.write.partitionBy("year").format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(delta_path)
start_date = "2019-01-21"
end_date = "2020-12-04"
start_year = int(start_date.split("-")[0])
end_year = int(end_date.split("-")[0])
**Reading the delta table and filtering the data based on the timestamp range and year**
delta_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_path)
df_filtered = delta_df.filter(
    (col("date") >= start_date) & (col("date") <= end_date) &
    (col("year") >= start_year) & (col("year") <= end_year)
)
df_filtered.show()
```

[image]

In the above code converting the timestamp column to a date column and create a year column for partitioning.

Write the dataFrame as a Delta table partitioned by the "**year**" column.
Read the Delta table and filter the data within the specified timestamp range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would work as well, but makes the code quite longer and harder to understand. I will keep it in my mind when generating columns is not an option anymore.